# Getting Started with ASP.NET MVC Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have started doing ASP.NET MVC, but I don't know where to start with this question.

I have created a default application and I have created an EventModel, EventController and a series of the default Event views.  It is all working correctly.

However, I want to make the routing work in the following way:

1. domain/events -> lists all events, sort of like domain/event does by default
2. domain/event/3 -> show a specific event (ID of 3), just like domain/details/3 does by default.
3. domain/event/cool-event -> show a specific event based on it's 'slug', which is a property of the EventModel
4. domain/event/edit/3 -> edits the event.

I have been playing around with the router and I can't get it to behave like I want it to.  Is the above logic easy to implement?

Comment: have you checked [attribute routing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx) yet?

Comment: It should be easy, yes -- that's a standard scenario.  All routes are easily distinguishable (2/3 based on the numeric check).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Attribute Routing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx) it could be like this (UNTESTED):

```
public class EventController : Controller
{
    //1. domain/events -> lists all events, sort of like domain/event does by default
    [Route("events")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //TODO: Add Action Code
        return View();
    }

    //2. domain/event/3 -> show a specific event (ID of 3), just like domain/details/3 does by default.
    [Route("event/id")]
    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        //TODO: Add Action Code
        return View();
    }

    //3. domain/event/cool-event -> show a specific event based on it's 'slug', which is a property of the EventModel
    [Route("event/{slug?}")]
    public ActionResult ViewEvent(string slug)
    {
        //TODO: Add Action Code
        return View();
    }

    //4. domain/event/edit/3 -> edits the event.
    [Route("event/edit/id")]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        //TODO: Add Action Code
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: ooo attribute routing is shiny!